# What are good ways to work around the encoding limitation of SKAction code blocks during application state preservation?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, uikit-state-preservation

## Problem

When the node hierarchy is encoded, as is common during application state preservation or a “game save”, nodes running `SKAction` actions with code blocks must be handled specially, since the code blocks cannot be encoded.

## Example 1: Delayed Callback after Animation

Here, an orc has been killed.  It is animated to fade out and then remove itself from the node hierarchy:

```
SKAction *fadeAction = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:3.0];
SKAction *removeAction = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[orcNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ fadeAction, removeAction ]]];
```

If the orc node is encoded and then decoded, the animation will restore properly and complete as expected.

But now the example is modified to use a code block that runs after the fade.  Perhaps the code cleans up some game state once the orc is (finally) dead.

```c
SKAction *fadeAction = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:3.0];
SKAction *removeAction = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *cleanupAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
  [self orcDidFinishDying:orcNode];
}];
[orcNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ fadeAction, removeAction, cleanupAction ]]];
```

Unfortunately, the code block will not encode.  During application state preservation (or game save), if this sequence is running, a warning will be issued:

> SKAction: Run block actions can not be properly encoded,
>   Objective-C blocks do not support NSCoding.

After decoding, the orc will fade and be removed from parent, but the cleanup method `orcDidFinishDying:` will not be called.

What is the best way to work around this limitation?

## Example 2: Tweening

The `SKAction` `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:` seems a beautiful fit for tweening.  My boilerplate code for this kind of thing is this:

```c
SKAction *slideInAction = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:2.0 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime){
  CGFloat normalTime = (CGFloat)(elapsedTime / 2.0);
  CGFloat normalValue = BackStandardEaseInOut(normalTime);
  node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, slideStartPositionY * (1.0f - normalValue) + slideFinalPositionY * normalValue);
}];
```

Unfortunately, `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:` cannot be encoded.  If the game is saved during the animation, it will not restore properly on game load.

Again, what is the best way to work around this limitation?

## Imperfect Solutions

Here are solutions I have considered but don’t like.  (That said, I’d love to read answers that successfully champion one of these.)

- Imperfect Solution: Use `performSelector:onTarget:` rather than `runBlock:` in the animation.  This solution is imperfect because arguments cannot be passed to the invoked selector; context for the call can only be expressed by the target and the name of the selector.  Not great.
- Imperfect Solution: During encoding, remove the `SKAction` sequence from any relevant nodes and advance the program state as if the sequence had completed.  In the first example, that would mean setting the node `alpha` immediately to `0.0`, removing the orc node from parent, and calling `orcDidFinishDying:`.  This is an unfortunate solution for at least two reasons: 1) It requires special handling code during encoding; 2) Visually, the node won’t get a chance to finish its animation.
- Imperfect Solution: During encoding, remove the `SKAction` code blocks from any relevant nodes, and recreate them during decoding.  This is non-trivial.
- Imperfect Solution: Never use `SKAction` code blocks, especially after a delay.  Never rely on the completion of an animation in order to restore good app state.  (If you need to schedule a future event in an encodable way, build your own event queue not using code blocks.)  This solution is imperfect because `runBlock` and `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:` are just so damn useful, and it would be a shame (and a recurring trap for newbies) to consider them evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encodable lightweight objects can model the kinds of `SKAction` code blocks that we want to use (but can’t).

Code for the below ideas is [here](https://github.com/hilogames/HLSpriteKit/blob/master/HLSpriteKit/HLHacktion.h).

### Replacement for `runBlock`

The first encodable lightweight object replaces `runBlock`.  It can make an arbitrary callback with one or two arguments.

- The caller instantiates the lightweight object and sets its properties: target, selector, and arguments.
- The lightweight object is triggered in a `runAction` animation by the standard no-argument `[SKAction performSelector:onTarget:]`.  For this triggering action, the target is the lightweight object and the selector is a designated “execute” method.
- The lightweight object conforms to `NSCoding`.
- As a bonus, the triggering `SKAction` retains a strong reference to the lightweight object, and so both will be encoded along with the node running the actions.
- A version of this lightweight object could be made that retains the target weakly, which might be nice and/or necessary.

Here is a draft of a possible interface:

```c
@interface HLPerformSelector : NSObject <NSCoding>

- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector argument:(id)argument;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id target;

@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL selector;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id argument;

- (void)execute;

@end
```

And an accompanying implementation:

```c
@implementation HLPerformSelector

- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector argument:(id)argument
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _target = target;
    _selector = selector;
    _argument = argument;
  }
  return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _target = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"target"];
    _selector = NSSelectorFromString([aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"selector"]);
    _argument = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"argument"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
  [aCoder encodeObject:_target forKey:@"target"];
  [aCoder encodeObject:NSStringFromSelector(_selector) forKey:@"selector"];
  [aCoder encodeObject:_argument forKey:@"argument"];
}

- (void)execute
{
  if (!_target) {
    return;
  }
  IMP imp = [_target methodForSelector:_selector];
  void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void (*)(id, SEL, id))imp;
  func(_target, _selector, _argument);
}

@end
```

And an example of using it:

```c
SKAction *fadeAction = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:3.0];
SKAction *removeAction = [SKAction removeFromParent];
HLPerformSelector *cleanupCaller = [[HLPerformSelector alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(orcDidFinishDying:) argument:orcNode];
SKAction *cleanupAction = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(execute) onTarget:cleanupCaller];
[orcNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[ fadeAction, removeAction, cleanupAction ]]];
```

### Replacement for `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`

A second encodable lightweight object replaces `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`.  This one is not so simple, however.

- Again, it is triggered by the no-argument `[SKAction performSelector:onTarget:]`, invoking a designated `execute` method.
- A `customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:` has a duration.  But the triggering `performSelector:onTarget:` does not.  The caller must insert a companion `waitForDuration:` action into her sequence if it depends on duration.
- The lightweight object is initialized with a target, selector, node, and duration.
- When it is triggered, the lightweight object tracks its own elapsed time and periodically calls the selector on the target, passing it the node and the elapsed time.
- The lightweight object conforms to `NSCoding`.  On decoding, if already triggered, it resumes calling the selector for the remainder of its configured duration.

### Limitations

I have implemented [a version of these proposed classes](https://github.com/hilogames/HLSpriteKit/blob/master/HLSpriteKit/HLHacktion.h). Through light use I've already found an important limitation: [Nodes encoded with a running `SKAction` sequence restart the sequence from the beginning upon decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36293846/1332415).